# Which of - carboxylic group or carbaldehyde group - has more negative inductive effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Which has more -I effect $\ce{-COOH}$ or $\ce{-CHO}$, and why?

I tried to analyze it on my own but I was confused on what to do. My teacher today taught it by shifting of electrons from $\ce{C=O}$ to the formation of a charge separated structure. Still, I was confused about it.
Mostly, I'm confused on why we are even allowed to create a charge separated structure. Even with it, it seems $\ce{-COOH}$ should have more -I effect. But I am not sure. I need help here.

Comment: Are you sure your teacher explained the -I effect by "the formation of a charge separated structure" and the -M effect instead?

Comment: Yes, he made the charged structure and I don't know why it was feasible. I'm not sure under what conditions we are allowed to do so. Sometimes these things seem to be bit mechanical and goes over my head.